# SQLite db isn't created

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, null

I have problem with sqlite database adapter in my project.I'm new to android development so I don't have much idea to how can handle this problem. I want to save user information in data base .Although no error while execution,database doesn't create? can any one help.

DatabaseAdapter :

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
private final String TAG = "DatabaseAdapter";
private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
public static final String TBL_PERSONS = "persons";
public static final String PERSON_ID = "_id";
public static final String PERSON_USERNAME = "_username";
public static final String PERSON_HEIGHT = "_height";
public static final String PERSON_WEIGHT = "_weight";
public static final String PERSON_AGE = "_age";
public static final String PERSON_GENDER = "_gender";
public static final String PERSON_PA = "_pa";
public static final String PERSON_BMI = "_bmivalue";
public static final String PERSON_INTERPRETATION = "_bmiInterpretation";
public static final String PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT = "_idealweight";
public static final String PERSON_DAILYCALORIES = "_dailycalories";

// ???????????
public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, "Persons.db", null, 1);
}

// ====================insert in
// database===========================================================
public Long insertPerson(Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Long id = -1L;
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("PERSON_USERNAME", person.getUsername());
        values.put("PERSON_HEIGHT", person.getHeight());
        values.put("PERSON_WEIGHT", person.getWeight());
        values.put("PERSON_AGE", person.getAge());
        values.put("PERSON_GENDER", person.getGender());
        values.put("PERSON_PA", person.getPa());
        values.put("PERSON_BMI", person.getBmivalue());
        values.put("PERSON_INTERPRETAION", person.getBmiInterpretation());
        values.put("PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT", person.getIdealweight());
        values.put("PERSON_DAILYCALORIES", person.getDailycalories());

        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        id = db.insert(TBL_PERSONS, null, values);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }
    return id;
}

// ================delete from
// database=============================================================

public int deletePerson(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    int count = -1;
    try {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        count = db.delete(TBL_PERSONS, PERSON_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    return count;
}

// ===============update
// database===================================================================

public int updatePerson(Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    int count = -1;
    try {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PERSON_USERNAME, person.getUsername());
        values.put(PERSON_HEIGHT, person.getHeight());
        values.put(PERSON_WEIGHT, person.getWeight());
        values.put(PERSON_AGE, person.getAge());
        values.put(PERSON_GENDER, person.getGender());
        values.put(PERSON_PA, person.getPa());
        values.put(PERSON_BMI, person.getBmivalue());
        values.put(PERSON_INTERPRETATION, person.getBmiInterpretation());
        values.put(PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT, person.getIdealweight());
        values.put(PERSON_DAILYCALORIES, person.getDailycalories());

        count = db.update(TBL_PERSONS, values, PERSON_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(person.getId()) });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    return count;
}

// ===================================================================DATABASEOPENHELPER
// CLASS=========================
class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = String
                .format("create table %s(%$ integer primary key,%s text,%s text,%s text,%s text,%s text,%s tetx,%s text,%s text,%s text,%s text)",
                        TBL_PERSONS, PERSON_ID, PERSON_USERNAME,
                        PERSON_HEIGHT, PERSON_WEIGHT, PERSON_AGE,
                        PERSON_GENDER, PERSON_PA, PERSON_BMI,
                        PERSON_INTERPRETATION, PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT,
                        PERSON_DAILYCALORIES);
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
}
```

person.java (I pass the user data to person.java)

```
package Databasedata;

public class Person {
private Long id;
private String username;
private float height;
private int weight;
private int age;
private String gender;
private String pa;
private int bmivalue;
private String bmiInterpretation;
private double idealweight;
private double dailycalories;
public double getIdealweight() {
    return idealweight;
}
public void setIdealweight(double idealweight) {
    this.idealweight = idealweight;
}
public double getDailycalories() {
    return dailycalories;
}
public void setDailycalories(double dailycalories) {
    this.dailycalories = dailycalories;
}


public int getBmivalue() {
    return bmivalue;
}
public void setBmivalue(int bmivalue) {
    this.bmivalue = bmivalue;
}
public String getBmiInterpretation() {
    return bmiInterpretation;
}
public void setBmiInterpretation(String bmiInterpretation) {
    this.bmiInterpretation = bmiInterpretation;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height =  height;
}
public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getPa() {
    return pa;
}
public void setPa(String pa) {
    this.pa = pa;
}   
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String gender;

RadioButton maleRadioButton;
RadioButton femaleRadioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    maleRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleselected);
    femaleRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleselected);

    final RadioGroup genderselected = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.selectgender);
    genderselected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId) {
            selectedId=genderselected.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton genderchoosed = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            gender= genderchoosed.getText().toString();


        }
    });

    Button saveinformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveinformation);
    saveinformation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        EditText weighttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weighttext);
        EditText heighttext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heighttext);
        EditText usernametext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernametext);
        EditText agetext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agetext);
        Spinner activitytext = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.chooseactivity);
        Button saveinformation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveinformation);
        String pa = activitytext.getSelectedItem().toString();




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(maleRadioButton.isChecked()) {
                gender= maleRadioButton.getText().toString();
            } else {
                gender = femaleRadioButton.getText().toString();
            }

            int weight = (int) Float.parseFloat(weighttext.getText()
                    .toString());
            float height =  Float.parseFloat(heighttext.getText()
                    .toString());
            String username = usernametext.getText().toString();
            int age = (int) Float.parseFloat(agetext.getText().toString());
            String pa = activitytext.getSelectedItem().toString();

            // BMI
            // ============================================================================================
            int Bmivalue = calculateBMI(weight, height);

            String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(Bmivalue);
            float idealweight = idealweight(weight, height, gender, pa, age);
            double dailycalories=dailycalories(weight,height,gender,pa,age);

            // insert in to
            // db==================================================================================
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setUsername(username);
            person.setHeight(height);
            person.setWeight(weight);
            person.setAge(age);
            person.setGender(gender);
            person.setPa(pa);
            person.setBmivalue(Bmivalue);
            person.setBmiInterpretation(bmiInterpretation);
            person.setIdealweight(idealweight);
            person.setDailycalories(dailycalories);
            // ?????????????????????????????????????????/
            Databasedata.DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new Databasedata.DatabaseAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this);
            dbAdapter.insertPerson(person);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    Bmivalue + "and you are" + bmiInterpretation,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

   }
   }
```

Comment: What's the specific problem? Is it that the table isn't there even though you have the SQL to create it in `onCreate()`? If so, chances are the database file already exists without the table. Just uninstall your app to get rid of the old file. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: @laalto I did it. I mean I uninstall app from my emulator "genymotion" and run app another time.but no answer.

Comment: So what's the specific problem? For example, exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: @laalto I checked logcat but no error . but when I check data base with sqlite manager nothing insert in table when I check found db doesn't create.

Comment: Are you using a pre-populated database?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob no I don't

Comment: `%$` is wrong. but you would know that if you cared to look at your error log.

Comment: @njzk2 I looked at logcat to find what exactly error is? but it dosent have error

Comment: I would recommend to add a pre-populated db, and use sqliteassethelper (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). It reduces errors and simplifies the process

Comment: look for something like `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '$'`, because, like I said, `%$ is wrong.`

Comment: @njzk2 aha,I find it. how can I solve this `%s`?

Comment: yes, just use %s like for all your other column names...

Comment: @njzk2 sorry I don't get what u said what u mean by 'using %s'. u mean I use %s insted of %$ in my code?

Comment: yes, just like you do for all the other columns.

Comment: @njzk2 I get waht u mean . thx :) please write ur answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

One Problem I see is in your insertPerson() method. Don't include the "" in the values.put()

try replacing below code

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("PERSON_USERNAME", person.getUsername());
    values.put("PERSON_HEIGHT", person.getHeight());
    values.put("PERSON_WEIGHT", person.getWeight());
    values.put("PERSON_AGE", person.getAge());
    values.put("PERSON_GENDER", person.getGender());
    values.put("PERSON_PA", person.getPa());
    values.put("PERSON_BMI", person.getBmivalue());
    values.put("PERSON_INTERPRETAION", person.getBmiInterpretation());
    values.put("PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT", person.getIdealweight());
    values.put("PERSON_DAILYCALORIES", person.getDailycalories());
```

with

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PERSON_USERNAME, person.getUsername());
    values.put(PERSON_HEIGHT, person.getHeight());
    values.put(PERSON_WEIGHT, person.getWeight());
    values.put(PERSON_AGE, person.getAge());
    values.put(PERSON_GENDER, person.getGender());
    values.put(PERSON_PA, person.getPa());
    values.put(PERSON_BMI, person.getBmivalue());
    values.put(PERSON_INTERPRETATION, person.getBmiInterpretation());
    values.put(PERSON_IDEALWEIGHT, person.getIdealweight());
    values.put(PERSON_DAILYCALORIES, person.getDailycalories());
```

Comment: I change them but no answer .